# Bootstrap TimePicker format with Angular 2+

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular5

I'm working with ***Angular4/Bootstrap4*** and I'm trying to set up my *dateTimePicker* format with **Angular** but in the documentation I found only the JQuery way!

## room.component.html:

```
  <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="timepicker" class="col-2 col-form-label">Time</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="time" value="13:45" #timepicker id="timepicker">
      </div>      
  </div>
```

## JQuery Solution (doc):

```
$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
    use24hours: true
});
```

I'm tring **to translate this solution from JQuery to Angular2+** but it doesn't work!

## room.component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('timepicker') private timepicker;

ngOnInit() {
    this.timepicker.datetimepicker({
      use24hours: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If so please accept the answer or provide feedback regarding additional issues.

Comment: Did this solution work for you?

Comment: Hi @Peter, At first I want to thank you for your collaboration, but the project was already delivered and I end up using the ng-bootstrap library which contain a TimePicker & a DatePicker.

Comment: Oh cool. Thanks for the follow up!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you still have to use jQuery in this example that you have provided. You will need to wrap the DOM element in a jQuery object in your component. Then you will be able to call the datetimepicker plugin method.

```js
//declare jQuery in component
declare var $: any;

ngOnInit() {
    $(this.timepicker).datetimepicker({
      use24hours: true
    });
}
```

The more jQuery way in Angular would be:

```js
//declare jQuery in component
declare var $: any;

ngOnInit() {
    $('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
      use24hours: true
    });
}
```